# How the Activity related to Window in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android, the concept *Window* seems not important anymore.

Comment: I fail to understand the question here. Please put some more effort in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until recently devices running Android have generally had small displays that would not be able to present multiple "windows" in a usable way.  Android best supports display of a single "window" covering the entire screen at any time - along with dialogs for convenience.  That window is typically managed by the system at the command of an Activity.  So yes .. in general you should forget about windows and use Activities to manage the UI.